# Biztalk 2013: Setting different namespace on schema elements

Tags: namespaces, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm developing a BizTalk application to query a number of web services that have been written and maintained by a third party, and I'm having some trouble getting the namespaces right on the Schemas.

Basically, I can't consume the wsdl to automatically generate the schemas because the namespaces and element names are all wrong within the generated schemas (due lazy C# wsdl generation), so I'm having to write them from scratch. This would be fine, but the Web Service endpoints are requiring that the elements within the schema all be qualified with specific namespaces, and none of them match the namespace of the overall schema.

I have figured out how to import other namespaces/schemas into my schema, but I can't figure out how to change the namespace of the elements to anything but the default. Does anyone know how to do this?

For example, the Schema root has to have a namespace of `"http:/tempuri.org/"`, but one of the elements requires the namespace `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ReadService.DTO.Inbound.Supplier"`, but within BizTalk, I can't edit the namespace of that element to change it.

The body of one of the requests looks like this:

```
<tem:GetSupplierIdWithExternalId>
     <tem:request>
        <com:Header>
           <com1:Username></com1:Username>
           <com1:Locale></com1:Locale>
        </com:Header>
        <read:ExternalSupplierId></read:ExternalSupplierId>
     </tem:request>
  </tem:GetSupplierIdWithExternalId>
```

"tem" in this case is http://tempuri.org/". "com", "com1" and "read" are all different namespaces, which, as Gruff has pointed out, are all default namespaces for WCF projects.

Generating from WSDL in Biztalk creates 2 issues:

1. The default namespace applied to the root note is not tempuri.org (as it recognises this as a default), it's the standard Biztalk http://..Folder.SchemaName namespace. Changing this to tempuri.org causes a cascade of errors that have to be fixed, and it doesn't resolve the more major issue which is:
2. Because of the way the WCF functions the WSDL has been generated from are written, the major element names (`GetSupplierIdWithExternalId` above) are all named incorrectly - in most cases, something like "GetSupplierIdWithExternalId**Request**", because that's the name of the function that schema is generate from. Again it's due to lazy programming on the endpoints, because the name of the element isn't being properly defined, it's just assumed by the generation process.

If I try and create a single flat file schema, I can only define a single namespace for the whole file, and if I set that to tempuri.org I get:

```
<ns0:GetSupplierWithExternalId xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Header>
    <Username>Username_0</Username>
    <Locale>Locale_0</Locale>
  </Header>
  <ExternalSupplierId>ExternalSupplierId_0</ExternalSupplierId>
</ns0:GetSupplierWithExternalId>
```

...which fails the a SOAP request because the namespaces on the internal elements aren't correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give more information around why you can't automatically generate the schemas? Why do you say the namespaces and element names are all wrong? What are they, and what do you expect them to be? Please supply examples, with only a couple fields to bring the point across?

Comment: @gruff Yep will do as soon as I'm back at a proper keyboard!

Comment: "due lazy C# wsdl generation"?  What exactly do you mean by this?  C# wsdl is not something we have in BizTalk?

Comment: @Johns-305, I've just added more detail. The WSDL generation I'm talking about it on the Endpoint I'm trying to contact - The C#/WCF Project I'm trying to communicate doesn't have properly defined namespaces for its elements, so when a WSDL was generated from the project, the schemas you get when you try to consume it in Biztalk are all wrong. Consuming it through another C# application is fine, because it "figures out" the correct SOAP structure using the same functionality, but Biztalk doesn't do that. (That's how it was explained to me anyway)

Comment: @IStanley When you consume the endpoint through another C# application, the proxy classes get generated from the metadata in the WSDL, which is the same information the schema wizard uses to generate the schema. Only difference is in BizTalk the schema layout is not hidden (abstracted) from you as in a C# project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define the element with the namespace of "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ReadService.DTO.Inbound.Supplier" in its own schema file, and import it into the schema root and compose the root that way. The element will keep the namespace it was defined as.

Looking at the namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ReadService.DTO.Inbound.Supplier", it seems it is the default namespace that WCF gives the data contract because it was not explicitly defined. (The CLR namespace of the class is ReadService.DTO.Inbound.Supplier) When the DataContractSerializer serializes the message when sending the request, it will serialize it with that namespace. You should not try and change it in the BizTalk schema, otherwise there will be a schema mismatch.

UPDATE:
In your update you mention 2 issues when generating the schema from the WSDL.

1. Can you paste a screenshot of this?
2. Are you sure `GetSupplierIdWithExternalIdRequest` is incorrect? If you search in the WSDL for that term, can you find it?
   The operation's request and response wrappers typically get suffixed with -Request and -Response, so this might be perfectly correct.

Comment: Hmmm. If I generate a sample XML using the schema and try to send that request using SOAPUI, I get a whole spate of errors due to namespace issues. Are you saying that this wouldn't happen if I sent the request using a BizTalk port, because the internal mechanisms would determine what namespaces are applied by default?

Comment: Yes, my advice would be to not try and change the namespaces in the schemas that are generated by the schema wizard. Then use Fiddler to monitor what the BizTalk WCF adapter on the send port actually sends over the wire.